# Old draggable elements stay on high charts after turning on and off data point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 4 data series.  Three  that are not draggable, and one that is called new contract.  The chart has the ability to turn on and off any of the data series.  However, when I change the draggable data, it seems the old, data is kept. Here is an example with salary cap, tax threshold, and payroll turned off.  I created this by dragging the "new contract" then turning on and off the "new contract"  [image: old data is kept]

I have a created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yc6epqge/ and am wondering how to fix this issue. Here is my code as well.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    animation: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22'],
    title: {
      text: 'Season'
    }
  },


  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: '$ Dollars'
    }
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderColor: '#2c3e50',
      point: {
        events: {
          drag: function(e) {
            $('#drag').html(
              'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2) + '</b>');
              if (this.category == "2016-17"){
                $('#season-1').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              }
              if (this.category == "2017-18"){
                $('#season-2').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              } 
              if (this.category == "2018-19")
              {
               $('#season-3').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              } 
              if (this.category == "2019-20"){
            $('#season-4').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
            } if (this.category == "2020-21"){
                $('#season-5').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
            }

          },
          drop: function() {
            $('#drop').html(
              'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
          }
        }
      },
      stickyTracking: false
    },
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    },
    line: {
      cursor: 'ns-resize'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Salary Cap',
    data: [94000000, 102000000, 108000000, 109000000, 114000000],
    visible: true
  }, {
    name: 'Tax Cap',
    data: [113000000, 122000000, 130000000, 132000000, 139000000]
  }, {
    name: 'New Contract',
    data: [10996155, 10996155, 10996155, 10996155, 10996155],
    draggableY: true,
    // drag: function() { console.log(arguments); },
    dragMinY: 0,
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 2,
    color: 'whitesmoke'
  }, {
    name: 'Current Payroll',
    data: [110492645, 103423474, 97903566, 62944822, 28751775],
    //draggableX: true,
    draggableY: false,
    dragMinY: 0,
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 2,
    color: '#2c3e50'
  }]
});

$('#season-1').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[0].update({
      y: val
    });
  });


$('#season-2').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[1].update({
      y: val
    });
  });


$('#season-3').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[2].update({
      y: val
    });
  });

$('#season-4').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[3].update({
      y: val
    });
  });
$('#season-5').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[4].update({
      y: val
    });
  });
$('#salarycap').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#container').highcharts().series[0].update({
      visible: val
    });
});
$('#taxthreshold').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#container').highcharts().series[1].update({
      visible: val
    });
});
$('#newcontract').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#container').highcharts().series[2].update({
      visible: val
    });
});
$('#currentpayroll').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#container').highcharts().series[3].update({
      visible: val
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of updating your series on changing your checkboxes, you should change their visibility only. In this case you can use Series.setVisible() method: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setVisible

```
$('#newcontract').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('#container').highcharts().series[2].setVisible(val);
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/yc6epqge/3/